# Identify location of old painting

Tags: germany, identify-this, where-on-earth

I received an old painting and wonder if it depicts a real place. The person I received the painting from, is from Germany (but unavailable for questions). However, the painting could very well be fictional and may or may not be a copy of a famous work.

Hopefully someone can either recognize the area or if is is a copy of a famous work then we may be able to find out the location.

[image]
Photograph 1
[image]
Photograph 2
[image]
Photograph 3
[image]
Photograph 4

I noticed that two ships in the picture feature a tricolored horizontal blue/black-white-red flag. This may hint to a potential location.
[image]
Flag option 1
[image]
Flag option 2

Considering that the previous owner is from Germany may be a strong hint to a location in Germany.

Comment: The name of the artist could be a hint. It's in the first image but kinda hard to decipher.

Comment: Might be Adolf Rheinert http://www.artnet.com/artists/adolf-rheinert/

Comment: Yes that could be it. FWIW I found a very similar painting by Eduard Schloemann, but that name doesn't resemble the signature at all. http://www.artnet.com/artists/eduard-schloemann ('Fartyg i hamnen', or 'Ship in harbour')

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The church in the picture looks pretty much like St. Michael's Church, Hamburg.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Michael%27s_Church,_Hamburg

Comment: Thank you for your response. I suppose there is not an a hundred percent safe answer but I select this answer anyway. Seems quite plausible!

Answer (score 9):

I consider both flags to be black-white-red and not blue-white-red, which makes them the colors of the merchant marine of the Norddeutscher Bund, Kaiserreich, or Weimarer Republik. The relatively modern design of the barge or small tugboat excludes the Norddeutscher Bund.

With hhm's probable identification of the Michaeliskirche, this would be Hamburg about a hundred years ago or perhaps a little more.