# Identify location (and painter) of old painting

Tags: germany, identify-this, riverboats, hamburg

I have received this painting from my grandma recently. However, she is unable to identify the location of this painting. Additionally, I am unsure about the name of the painter (lower right corner). I think I know what it is, but I will not add it to prevent priming you guys.
Also, if you have any ideas to where I could post this question too, I am open to suggestions!

[image: Complete image]

[image: Middle]

[image: Left]

[image: Right]

[image: Name]

[image: Name zoomed in]

Comment: A nautical expert could probably provide an approximate date based on the ship and boats.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that this question was posted on the day exactly 1 year after [this oddly similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/151582/41995)? Is there a popular tradition of people giving away mysterious paintings of ships and tugboats in Hamburg with Sankt Michaelis church tower in the background around Christmas?

Comment: @jkej Oh wow, I did not know that! It is a coincidence indeed. I don't know about the other question, but this was just because my grandma moved, so I don't think it's related haha.

Comment: Possibly Fritz Muller? https://www.johnmoran.com/auction-lot/fritz-muller-b-1814-german-american-auxilliary-st_EB1415AB5E

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about travel in the scope defined in the [help]. All "where in the world" questions are somewhat borderline, but this one does not even attempt the facade of being a place one would want to visit or a method by which one would want to visit. This is art identification, not travel.

Answer (score 26):

The church tower on the third picture looks like [Sankt Michaelis (Michel)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Michael%27s_Church,_Hamburg) in Hamburg. The tower was rebuilt into it's current form after it burned down in 1906 so this dates the painting as being done later than 1906.

[image]

<sub>Source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hamburg-Michaeliskirche-Hafen.jpg</sub>

---

From the comments (thanks [@emil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30864/emil)):

- The building left of the Michel church tower is the [Seewetteramt, former Navigationsschule](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigationsschule_(Hamburg)) (build in 1905) and the tower to the right of the largest ship is the clock tower of [Kaispeicher A (Kaiserspeicher)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaispeicher_A) (demolished in 1963, the second Kaispeicher A building became the lower part of the [Elbphilharmonie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbphilharmonie) in 2007). This also puts some time constraints on when the painting was made and it puts the location close to the St. Pauli Piers.
- The fact that the church tower is green in the painting but appears dark in recent pictures is not surprising: The copper cladding of the tower was renewed in 2009 and will take some years before it develops a green patina again

---

The name of the artist seems to be "F. Müller". Müller (Miller) is a very common name in Germany, so you might need an art specialist to find out details. [Franz Müller-Gossen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_M%C3%BCller-Gossen) might fit but seems to have a different signature and a slightly different style, it also could be somebody who hasn't left traces in the Internet.

Comment: I thought of Franz Müller-Gossen, too, but his signature looks differently - additionally, he seemed to have signed using his full name, not just "F. Müller".

Comment: @tohuwawohu Ah, right. Didn't find anything to compare to.

Comment: Wow, it does resemble the church a lot indeed! Thank you, I will look it up. 

As for the name, my initial guess was F. Möller, which led me to [Fyodor Antonovich Moller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Friedrich_Theodor_von_Möller), but this work does not show up at his gallery and his style does also seem to differ from my painting. The signature is also different from what I've seen.

Comment: I have looked it up. Don't you mean the third picture? (my post was not properly formatted before. Thank you @tohuwahu) Because that could mean you're right and the church in the second picture could be [Saint Katherine's Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Catherine%27s_Church,_Hamburg).

Comment: @BaeBrowns Now it‘s the third, right :-)

Comment: I want to confirm that this is very likely Hamburg: The building left of the Michel church tower is the [Seewetteramt, former Navigationsschule](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigationsschule_(Hamburg)) (build in 1905) and the tower to the right of the largest ship is the clock tower of [Kaiserspeicher A](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaispeicher_A) (demolished in 1963). This also puts some time constraints on when the painting was made and it puts the location close to the St. Pauli Piers.

Comment: By the way, the fact that the church tower is green in the painting but appears dark in recent pictures is not surprising: The copper cladding of the tower was renewed in 2009 and will take some years before it develops a green patina again.

Comment: @emil Thanks for these additions, I've included them in the answer. And I learned that the Kaispeicher became the lower part of the Elbphilharmonie building :-)

Comment: The tug boats in the picture look like those on historical photographs of the port of Hamburg from [1903](http://www.hamburg-bildarchiv.de/XBA2086.jpg) and [1905](http://www.hamburg-bildarchiv.de/XC1095.jpg).

Comment: There is a Fritz Müller, who was a marine painter and lived in Hamburg, but the years don't match the construction dates of the buildings: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz_M%C3%BCller_(Maler,_1814)

Comment: Signature doesn't really match either: https://www.invaluable.com/auction-lot/fritz-muller-b-1814-german-american-auxil-248-c-eb1415ab5e

Comment: @Emil Thank you for noticing that! It gives a more complete understanding of the painting.

Comment: @mrks Yeah, I've looked into Fritz Müller too, but his style and signature differ indeed.

Comment: @BaeBrowns The church tower as seen was built in/after 1906, so a 19th century painter doesn't qualify :-)